# Elasticsearch- how to do multi search request on Sense or Head plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to achieve this multi search request on sense and plugin head but I am not able to get what could be the problem?
sample on [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search) is for curl, I cant comprehend what is the exact difference.

```
POST _msearch?pretty=1 
{"myIndex":"Product"}
{
  "fields": [
      "id",
    "Name"
  ], 
"query": {
 "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "_all",
            "query": "key"
          }
        }
      ] 
    }      

  }
,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
{"myIndex":"Printer"}{
  "fields": [
      "id",
    "Name"  
  ], 
"query": {
 "bool": { 
      "must": [{
      "has_child": {
     "type": "Printer",
     "query": {
        "match": {
        "Name": "key"
        }
      }
    }
      }]
    }      

  }
,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

I am getting this error on sense. 
{
   "error": "JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: [B@48acbc4c; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@48acbc4c; line: 1, column: 3]]",
   "status": 500
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of extra spaces. I got this error removed by removing extra space and next lines.
In sense  Run `ctrl+I` twice to first indent and then un-indent the query.

Hope this will remove the error.

Comment: On running multisearch , You should get array of responses with 2 elements.Each should have 5 results